# NSURL URLWithString returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl, nsstringencoding

I am stuck in a very obvious method of `NSURL` class `URLWithString` I am passing a `string` and while creating `URL` it returns `nil`, my `string` is perfect. When ever I uses same string in browser then it is working fine. I am using following method to convert `NSString` to `NSURL`:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
//urlString is my perfect string
```

I have also tried to encode my string first by using following

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// using this line my output string when I log url is "url%10%10%10%10%10%10..."
```

`%10 becomes the suffix of my url with around 100+ repetition`.
If any one has idea what `%10` is or what can be done to overcome this problem.

here is my `urlString`:
[image: comment says too many character but it is obvious that there are not much characters]

Comment: What is the exact value of `urlString`?

Comment: `%10` is a hex code. That's `16` in decimal which is a strange control character. Show where `urlString` comes from and again, show its exact value.

Comment: please see my edited answer, i have posted an image which showing my url string in comment and site is saying too many characters

Comment: Add the following code: `NSLog(@"urlString = \"%@\"", urlString);` then update your question with the output from that log statement.

Comment: And where does this value come from? You obviously have a lot of extra strange characters in the value. Clean the value up.

Comment: yes, i have re Written my link, i do not know what actually happened to my string but this comment gave me idea that there is something invisible. rewriting solved my problem. was stuck in it for last 4 hours

Comment: %10 = "data link escape" according to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp. Did you try using `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`? Btw, if you've already found a solution (based on your comments) I think you could post your solution to help others in the future.

Comment: Your string is "too long by 12205 characters". Seems to contain loads of rubbish. I wouldn't worry about NSURL, but I would worry about the string.

Comment: Yes, I figured out solution by this when I was updating my question post. Thanks all

Comment: how to remove %10 from url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes what was wrong in my string were many unidentified characters due to copying from internet site, if anyone of the reader facing this issue can copy and paste your string as see the count. And confirm.
Thanks

Comment: So, it wasn't a _perfect string_ as stated in your question. You may use https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/ to see invisible characters from a string.

Answer (score 3):

Use below code to resolve your problem.

```
NSString *str = msgDetail[@"thumbnail"];

NSString* webStringURL = [str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];

NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];
```

Answer (score -2):

Try below solution

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Check it..!

Comment: No, `%10` is not "@", "@" is `%40`. You are reading the chart incorrectly. `%10` is the hex value 10 which is the decimal value 16. That is the "data link escape" control character. And the "solution" you posted in your answer is what the OP is already showing in their question.

Comment: @rmaddy
See properly the question..It is having stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding
But in my answer I applied different i.e; stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding. Check properly before down vote...

Comment: @SyedAliSalman.. Check properly what you have tried..
U tried with stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding but In my answer I used stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding..
Check properly and down vote...!

Comment: Using stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding is even more incorrect. The original string doesn't have any percent escapes to replace.